# How to pin down the cause of a NullPointerException on DelegatingFilterProxy?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

Following a guide (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/6/) on spring.io, I am migrating my application to Spring 4. I run into a NullPointerException after having the SecurityWebAppInitializer as shown in the guide. The following is the trace stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

The full stack is the followings:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The error stack doesn't show much information. How to pin down its cause and resolve this error?

I use a Java configuration in the same way as shown in the guide. The WebAppInitializer and SecurityWebAppInitializer are the same as the guide.

```
@Order(2)
public class WebAppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebSecurityConfig.class, JPAConfig.class, CoreConfig.class, FacebookConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
}

}

@Order(1)
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer
extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer { }
```

And a section of the WebConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource({ "classpath:mail.properties",
    "classpath:express.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp.account.web" })
@Import({CoreConfig.class})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   ....
}
```

And WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

The exception doesn't occur after I remove SecurityWebAppInitializer or comment out its parent class AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.
Thanks for your inputs in advance.

Comment: could you post the full stacktrace and some spring configuration, the web.xml is also important

Comment: Here is the full stack trace:

Comment: Where is the `DelegatingFilterProxy` declared?

Comment: @Sotirios My app doesn't use DeletegtingFilterProxy directly.

Answer (score 0):

As you are migrating to Spring 4, did you remove from your web.xml the `springSecurityFilterChain`? It seems the spring security configuration in your current application is interfering with the new annotation based configuration.

Namely the delating filter proxy of Spring security is being configured with a null `targetBeanName`, which causes the null pointer exception. This is not possible if only the `SecurityWebAppInitializer` comes into play.

Also you could put some breakpoints in the D`elegatingFilterProxy` constructors and the setter for targetBeanName, to see who is setting it to null.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am migrating from a XML configuration to Java configuration. There isn't a web.xml file in the new version and DelegatingFilterProxy is in the web.xml file of the old version. I need to figure out how to add this one accordingly in Java configuration. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: After some online searching and test, I haven't had any luck so far. One blog says that an extension of  AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer would cover the DelegatingFilterProxy. That seems to be right. The guide sample works with the configuration and my app doesn't have any special Spring Security usages. Some other blogs say that an override onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) with servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
    new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*"); I get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception as default bean name was getting set as null, resolved the issue by explicitly setting the bean name as 'springSecurityFilterChain' in the DelegatingFilterProxy constructor

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter, new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")};
}
```

Comment: you're better off using AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME vs a string in the DelegatingFilterProxy  constructor.